# Score book to keep track of games

Tags: board-game-geek

I've seen multiple questions/answers about keeping track of all the games you and your friends play via websites and apps. However, I haven't seen any around a physical book that enables recording scores. I understand the book wouldn't have the flexibility of a website, but in my case the physical nature of the book is more appropriate. I'm currently using a regular old notebook and it works find but isn't fun or interesting to look at. Is there anything that is a little more fun and appropriate for keeping a history of game played, score, date, players involved, etc.